# AJAX not processing forms after first form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have forms created dynamically with php while loop. these forms have unique ID and there's and input inside each form with the same name and ID.

```
<form name="<?php echo $school_ID; ?>" action="http://example.com/edit-school-process.php" class="form-horizontal edit_school" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="school_name" id="school_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $school_name; ?>">
<label for="school_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">school name</label>
</form>
```

there are couple of these forms created but with the code below, ajax just detects first form and nothing with the rest

```
$('.edit_school').submit(function(event) {
$this = $(this);
var formData = {
'school_name'             : $('input[name=school_name]').val(),
'identity'                : $this.attr("name"),
};
```

what should i do to process all forms. THANK YOU...

Comment: You can only use an id once per page FYI

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your form one by one with each function

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.edit_school').each(function(){
        obj = $(this);
        obj.submit(function(event) {
            var formData = {
            'school_name'             : obj.find('input[name=school_name]').val(),
            'identity'                : obj.attr("name"),
            };
        });
    }) 
});
```

something like this may work